# Graph terminology: Are there terms for "a source or a sink" and for "neither source nor sink"?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, directed-graphs

I often have to write something like "let $v$ be a vertex of the graph $G$ that is a sink or a source" or "that is neither a sink nor a source". Are there single-word terms for such notions? For example, for a function, "a point that is a maximum or a minimum" is called an *extremum*, and I would call "a point that is neither maximum nor minimum" a *non-extremum*. Are there such terms for digraphs?

Specifically, is there a term for a vertex of a digraph for which in-degree or out-degree is zero?

Is there a term for a vertex of a digraph that has both incoming and outgoing edges? I have seen people calling such vertices *internal*, but this seems not to be a common term (other than referring to non-leaf vertices in a tree, which is a completely different usage).

Comment: The answer to these "is there a standard term for it" questions is generally "if you have to ask, then you should assume that there isn't, and the listener/reader will benefit from you defining any term that you choose to use for it."

Comment: @NoName No, that's not usually the answer. If that were generally the answer, we wouldn't have a [tag:terminology] tag on this website. Of course it is nice to define terms you use, but it is *also* good to use terms that people already have used, rather than make up your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some prior art, but nothing that will be universally recognized.

In the context of [series-parallel digraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_graph), the source and sink are called the *terminals* of the graph. This is a slightly more specific case, but you might adopt it for general digraphs.

As you've mentioned, there's *internal* and its cousins *interior* and *intermediate*, which I expect to fill in the blank in a sentence along the lines of

> In a network flow problem, flow conservation must hold at every ______ vertex.

But it's equally common even for people studying network flows to just suffer through the awkwardness of saying "at every vertex other than the source and sink". Unfortunately, internal vertices can also mean the non-endpoints of a path (which at least is not too far from this usage) or the vertices of a planar graph not on the external face of a given plane embedding.

Specifically in [multi-commodity network flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-commodity_flow_problem), we might also call the intermediate nodes the *transit* nodes, but (in my opinion, at least) it makes less sense to use this terminology for a general digraph.

Comment: Thank you! Why doesn't *transit nodes* make sense for a general digraph? The other answer implies that *transshipment nodes* makes sense for a general digraph; I assume this uses the same metaphor as *transit* nodes, but *transit* is shorter and less awkward.

Comment: I will edit my answer to clarify that it's my own opinion (and I'd be reluctant to say "transshipment" for a general digraph, too). When you're solving a network flow problem, there is actually "transit" happening through the transit nodes; when you're talking about an abstract directed graph, that makes less sense.

Answer (score 1):

The nodes other than the source(s) or sink(s) are often called *transshipment* nodes.  See, for example, the second page of http://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-08.pdf